# Cant able to access WinBUGS code in R using R2WinBUGS

Tags: loops, for-loop, winbugs, r2winbugs, winbugs14

I have the model specification in WinBUGS and I have specified all the parameters, initials in the R console. While using the bugs() function say,
bugs(data, parameters, initial,model.file="c:/ProgramFiles/WinBUGS14/sample1",n.chain,n.iters,bugs.directory="c:/ProgramFiles/WinBUGS14/")
I'm getting a warring message saying, "c:/ProgramFiles/WinBUGS14/sample1" does not exist. Can anyone help to crack this, please?